# Axios won't post and throws "network error"

Tags: javascript, post, axios, fetch

```
const Sign_up = () => {
    const [UserRegisteration] = useRegisterUserMutation();
    "127.0.0.1:8000/api/register/"
    const [homeScreen, setHomeScreen] = React.useState({
        username :'',
        email : '',
        password : '',
        repassword: '',
        // tc : null,

    });
    const navigateCheck = async () => {
        const formData = {username : homeScreen.username, email : homeScreen.email, password: homeScreen.password, repassword: homeScreen.repassword, tc : homeScreen.tc}
        if (homeScreen.password === homeScreen.repassword){
            axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/register/', {
                formData
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            const res = await UserRegisteration(formData)
            console.log("Response", res)
            if (res.data) {
                console.log("Response Data", res.data)
                await storeToken(res.data.token)  // Store Token in Storage
                clearTextInput()
                navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
            }
        }
             else {
                ;Alert.alert(
                    "Incorrect E-mail",
                    "You entered your E-mail/password incorrectly",
                    [
                        {text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("pressed ok")}
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
```

I get the response of  LOG  Response {"error": {"error": "TypeError: Network request failed", "status": "FETCH_ERROR"}}
LOG  [AxiosError: Network Error]
please help

I tried using other method but they all failed too

Comment: Seems like the url is wrong

Comment: I tried 192...etc and it didn't work either